# How to create custom Contact Us page in Magento 2 (Claue)

Tags: magento2, theme

This question/topic is not directly related to Magento, but a 3rd party theme (Claue). Now I know I should contact their support, unfortunately they are replying very late and I already did contact them but ever since (3 days) I have been waiting. Therefore, I thought of getting help from developers who (possibly) might have worked with Claue Theme.

I installed Magento without sample data, then installed Claue theme. But I see no `contact us` page. Unfortunately, in their [documentation](http://www.magesolution.com/themes/claue/docs/m2/index.html#contact-page) there is no details about this issue or solution, creating custom pages. So, I created new contact page from `"admin > content > pages"` but now I am stuck as how do I get claue contact-us form or Map API.

**Currently my contact us page looks like:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create it step by step.

1. Add new a page: admin > content > pages. On the action column select and view then note the URL of the page
2. Admin: MGS > Manage MegaMenu Items > Add items (select Menu Types as Static Content) In the link input box, insert the URL you copied.
3. Flush Menu Cache or clear the entire cache.